# I want to restart the event without reloading. Infinite or multiple times

Tags: javascript

Roughly Saturdays from 10:00 to 13:00 in the United States.

It seems that England is around 18:00 on Saturday.

I thought this timing was the best, so I posted it now.

I'm using unfamiliar English sentences, so I'm sorry if something goes wrong.

Using the following code, I succeeded in starting with a key operation and stopping at a click event.

However, the event will not resume unless you reload the screen.

```
// "Alt" + "Shift" + "↓" automatic scrolling
$(function() {
  var m;
  $(window).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.altKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 40) {
      if(!m){
        m=setInterval(function(s){
          scrollBy(0,s||1);
        },35);
      }
    }
  });
  $(document).on('click', function() {
    //location.reload(true);
    clearInterval(m);
  });
});
```

Useless
location.reload (true);
Sentence,
.on ('click', function () {
I tried to write, but it doesn't work because the screen reloads every time I click.

If possible, I would like to stop the screen without reloading, then restart the event and stop it again. How can I enable such an operation?

Please teach me.

Operating environment
Windows 10
Chrome 64bit
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/css-and-javascript-inject/ckddknfdmcemedlmmebildepcmneakaa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is `m = undefined` in your `click` event handler.

When you use a variable in a condition like that Javascript will evaluate it's "truthiness". The "falsey" values are undefined, null, zero, empty string, NaN, and of course boolean false. Everything else is truthy, including the handle returned by `setInterval` (which in the browser is a non-zero integer) which you assign to m. Clearing the interval does not reset the variable, you need to do it yourself.

I would also recommend you to avoid using jQuery as it doesn't help you much in this case - your entire code snippet can be rewritten with vanilla JS and modern [Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API) features, at least. For example:

```js
// "Alt" + "Shift" + "↓" automatic scrolling
;(() => {
  let m

  const scrollBy = () => {
    console.log('called scrollBy()')
  }

  window.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
    if (m === undefined && e.altKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 40) {
      m = setInterval(s => scrollBy(0, s||1), 35)
    }
  })

  document.addEventListener('click', () => {
    clearInterval(m)
    m = undefined
  })
})()
```

Finally, `s` may not be what you think it is. You should probably check out the MDN documentation for [`Window.setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval).

Comment: Solid answer, +1. Hope you don't mind, I added a bit of explanation of why.

Comment: @JaredSmith Don't mind at all. Thanks for the assist!

Comment: thank you for your answer.　

m = undefined;

　Just by adding this code to the end, I was able to implement the desired functionality with JQuery. Thank you very much.

I'm just curious about JS, so I'm sorry I have no knowledge at all, but there are some mysterious things.

It seems to be an "arrow function",　

; (() => {

　I don't really understand the meaning of this description.

What is that?

Thank you again.
Thank you.

Comment: @appren_tice It's alright if you don't get it, yet! I put `m = undefined` first just in case you didn't ;). Mostly, an arrow function works the same and just looks a bit different from a traditional function. You don't need to type as much because a lot of parts are optional, like parentheses or `return`. That's oversimplifying just a bit, but it works pretty well to get to know them at first, I think. For more info, this [part of MDN may help](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Comparing_traditional_functions_to_arrow_functions)